# Отключить вкладку на странице товара, если в ней нет добавленных товаров WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я использую код, который выводит вкладку "Сопутствующие товары" на отдельной странице товара.

```
// Display a multiselect field in "Linked Products" section
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_related', 'display_handles_product_field' );
function display_handles_product_field() {
    global $product_object, $post;
    ?>
    <h2><strong>Сопутствующие товары во вкладках</strong></h2>
    <p class="form-field">
        <label for="handles_product"><?php _e( 'Сопутствующие товары', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <select class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" id="handles_product_ids" name="_handles_product_ids[]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations" data-exclude="<?php echo intval( $post->ID ); ?>">
            <?php
                $product_ids = $product_object->get_meta( '_handles_product_ids' );

                foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
                    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                    if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '"' . selected( true, true, false ) . '>' . wp_kses_post( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <?php
}

// Save the values to the product
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_handles_product_field_value', 10, 1 );
function save_handles_product_field_value( $product ){
    $data = isset( $_POST['_handles_product_ids'] ) ? array_map( 'intval', (array) $_POST['_handles_product_ids'] ) : array();
    $product->update_meta_data( '_handles_product_ids', $data );
}


/* New Handles Product Tab */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'new_handles_product_tab' );
function new_handles_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    
    /* Add new tab */
    $tabs['new_handles_product_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Сопутствующие товары', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'new_handles_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}

function new_handles_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    
    $product_ids = $product->get_meta( '_handles_product_ids' ); // Get handles
    
    if( ! empty($product_ids) )
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);
        
        echo do_shortcode( "[products ids='$product_ids' columns='4']" ); // Using [products] shortcode for display.
}
```

Код рабочий, но есть небольшая проблема. Если во вкладке "Сопутствующие" нет вручную добавленных товаров, тогда выводятся все товары магазина.

Подскажите, как это можно исправить? Как можно отключить вкладку, если в ней нет добавленных товаров?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

думаю вот так должно сработать

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'new_handles_product_tab' );
function new_handles_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $product;
    
    $product_ids = $product->get_meta( '_handles_product_ids' );

    if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) { 

        /* Add new tab */
        $tabs['new_handles_product_tab'] = array(
            'title'     => __( 'Сопутствующие товары', 'woocommerce' ),
            'priority'  => 50,
            'callback'  => 'new_handles_product_tab_content'
        );
    }

    return $tabs;
}

function new_handles_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;

    $product_ids = $product->get_meta( '_handles_product_ids' ); // Get handles

    if( ! empty($product_ids) ) {
        $product_ids = implode(',', $product_ids);
    
        echo do_shortcode( "[products ids='$product_ids' columns='4']" );
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все работает.