# Аналоги товаров в Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин автозапчастей на CMS Wordpress + Woocommerce

Надо в карточках товаров добавить блок с аналогами товаров.

Блок добавил (нашел готовое решение) вот код:

```
function my_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary() {
global $product;
if ($sku = $product->get_sku()) { // проверяем, задан ли артикул товара
        $args = array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
        'no_found_rows'        => 1,
        'post_not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
        'orderby'              => 'title',
        'order'                => 'ASC',
        's'                    => $sku
        );

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        echo  "<h3>Аналоги запчасти: $sku </h3>";
        echo '<table><tr><th></th><th>Наименование</th><th>Цена</th></tr>';
        $count_table = 1;
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product_title = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
            global $product;
            $product_price = wc_price($product->get_price());
            echo "<tr><td>$count_table</td><td>$product_title</td><td>$product_price</td></tr>";
            $count_table++;
        }
        echo '</table>';  
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();  
}
}

add_filter('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 13 );
```

Пример работы этого кода можно увидеть [тут](https://vagparts.kiev.ua/vozdushnyj-filtr/filtr-vozdushnyj-vag-7p0129620a/)

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы на товарах, где нет аналогов - не показывать этот блок (потому что сейчас показывается тот же товар, на котором находится пользователь, получается циклическая ссылка) - [вот](https://vagparts.kiev.ua/elektrooborudovanie/generator-vag-06b903016ab/)

Comment: аналогично https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270311/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-woocomm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы видите текущий пост в аналогах, потому что у вас в аргументах запроса есть неправильный ключ `post_not_in` из-за которого вы не исключаете текущий товар из запроса.
Для того что бы исключить текущий товар из запроса вам нужно заменить этот ключ `post_not_in` на вот этот `post__not_in` тогда аргументы будут иметь следующий вид

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id ),
    'orderby'              => 'title',
    'order'                => 'ASC',
    's'                    => $sku
);
```